# Breakpoint is set in the wrong place in xcode

Tags: xcode, clang, xcode7, llvm

I have a strange situation where I'm trying to set a breakpoint in XCode and it's being set at the wrong place. I looked at many previous messages and tried many things:
Clean build and build folder, delete derived data, restart everything, upgrade xcode (now in 7.2.1).
I see that the breakpoint is in the wrong place when I use command "breakpoint list". this happens only when I run on a device (both iPad and iPhone) but not in simulator.
I suspect that still I have some strange optimizations even though I made sure Optimization Level is -O0 and I'm in debug.

When I put the breakpoint on the problematic method, it gets thrown down to the next method, but if I add a call to that method from the same file, it works properly.

Anyone have an idea what can be done? maybe there is another configuration that causes optimizations.

Thanks!